# Why the value Vector3.Distance return become bigger when two object close to each other

Tags: unity-game-engine

As the title said, I use **Vector3.Distance** to get two objects' distance, something like enemy chase player,
and I found that even the enemy "catch" the player, the two object is close to each other, I mean they're all in same position, overlaping each other, but the value this api return is not what I thought, the value is keeping in around 0 for a little while, then it start to became larger and larger.
I wonder if has some reason to explain that, it's weird.

I use NavMeshAgent to set "player.transform.position" as destination.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jTJe.png)

another image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzLlX.png)

```
public override void Reason(GameObject player, GameObject npc)
{
    NPCControl npcControl = npc.GetComponent<NPCControl>();
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(npc.transform.position, player.transform.position);

    Vector3 Ppos = player.transform.position;
    Debug.Log("P(" + Ppos.x + ", " + Ppos.y + ", " + Ppos.z + ")");
    Vector3 Epos = npc.transform.position;
    Debug.LogWarning("E(" + Epos.x + ", " + Epos.y + ", " + Epos.z + ")");
    float Dst = Vector3.Distance(Ppos, Epos);
    Debug.LogError("P-E(" + Dst + ")");
}
```

**Solution：**
I change the part of code like following, the reason why ths problem happen is still need to dig deeper.

```
Vector3 from = new Vector3(npc.transform.position.x, 0f, npc.transform.position.z);
    Vector3 to = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x, 0f, player.transform.position.z);
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(from, to);
```

Comment: This is not a lot to go on, can you post the values?

Comment: well probably because you either didn't pass in the correct values or use it incorrectly .. hard to tell without seeing your code

Comment: I post the value. seems the enemy's position.y is keeping changing

Comment: It would be good to use Vector2.Distance if you are making a 2d game.

Answer (score 0):

what you could try is:

assign the 2 objects you want the distance between in the 2 public variables below

```cs
public GameObject Object1;
public GameObject Object2

private float distance;

void Update()
{
    distance = Vector3.Distance(Object1.transform.position, Object2.transform.position);
    Debug.Log(distance);
}
```

this seems to be the most simple and effective way of doing it.